# String Token strtok function logic

Tags: c, string, strtok

I am learning string manipulation with C Standard Functions. When I am learning this stuff, I am facing with strtok function and the following code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str[80] = "This is - www.tutorialspoint.com - website";
   const char s[2] = "-";
   char *token;

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL )
   {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

I don't understand why in while loop, strtok used with null? Why null used here? Because in strtok function definition comes something like (this function breaks first paramter string into a series of tokens using the second paramter of itself.)

Comment: This is a case where you need to Read The Friendly Manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it uses an internal `static` pointer to the string you are working with, so if you want it to operate on the same string, you just need to call it with `NULL` as the first argument and let it use it's internal pointer. If you call it with non-null first argument then it will overwrite the pointer with the new pointer.

This means in turn, that `strtok()` is not reentrant. So you normally just use it in simple situations, more complex situations where reentrance is important (*like multithreaded programs, or working on multiple strings*) require different approaches.

One way is on POSIX systems where you can use `strtok_r()` which takes one extra argument to use as it's "*internal*" pointer.

Check [this manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) to learn about it more.

Answer (score 4):

`strtok` uses an internal (static) state to tokenize a string. When called with NULL, it goes to the next token in the string that was passed in the first call.

It is worth mentioning, that this property (internal state) makes it unsafe to use in multi-threaded environment. A safer version is `strtok_r`, which return the state as an output parameter.

Comment: @iharob POSIX is a standard ;-)

Comment: Well yes that's true ... My comment wasn't clear in that sense.

Answer (score 2):

The first call you use a char array which has the elements you want parsed.
The second time you call it you pass it `NULL` as the first parameter to tell function to resume from the last spot in the string. Once the first call is made your `char` array receives the parsed string. If you don't put `NULL` you would lose your place and effectively the last part of your string.

```
char * c_Ptr = NULL;        //temp hold indivisual sections
char c_Ptr1[1000] = {NULL};
fgets(c_Ptr1, 1000, f_ptr); //Grabs a line from an open file
strtok(c_Ptr1, ",");        //first one starts at the beginning 
c_Ptr = strtok(NULL, ",");
```